# Create permalinks in HTML using tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

Use case: an HTML version of a developer guide written in LaTeX and knowledge base articles in HTML which should be able to link to a certain section, figure, code snippet, ... in the HTML version of the developer guide.

When the developer guide gets updated (e.g. a new section is inserted), the links in the knowledge base articles should still point to the correct entry.

To be more concrete, consider the following input

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First}\label{sec:first}
A first section \autoref{sec:first}.

\section{Second}\label{sec:second}
A second section \autoref{sec:second}.

\end{document}
```

Converting this to HTML using the `htlatex test.tex "xhtml,3,frames"` command results in files:

- First section: testse1.html
- Second section: testse2.html

If I now insert a section

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First}\label{sec:first}
A first section \autoref{sec:first}.

\section{Inserted}\label{sec:inserted}
An inserted section \autoref{sec:inserted}

\section{Second}\label{sec:second}
A second section \autoref{sec:second}.

\end{document}
```

and process that again using the same command, the file `testse2.html` suddenly contains the "Inserted" section and no longer the "Second" section. Links to the "Second" section must suddenly point to `testse3.html`.

This problem not only applies to pages, but also to anchors in existing pages (e.g. to link to a specific figure or code snippet).

- Is there a way to configure the file name to match e.g. the `\label` which is used in the source file
- Is there a way to somehow dump some output with matches the generated files and anchors to the `\label`s used in the input files. I could then probably use this output to introduce intermediate links which can act as "permalink", or any other post-processing steps.
- Is there another mechanism available to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ulrike said, you can use `\NextFile`, but I would  use some automation in the process, also, it is not a good idea to insert `tex4ht` macros directly in the document:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mysection}

\begin{document}
%\tableofcontents

\mysection{First}{sec:first}
A first section \autoref{sec:first}. But more interesting stuff is in \autoref{sec:second}

\mysection{Inserted}{sec:inserted}
An inserted section \autoref{sec:inserted}

\mysection{Second}{sec:second}
A second section \autoref{sec:second}.

\end{document}
```

The `\mysection` command will insert `\label` automatically and it will enable use to name the file. It is defined as follows in `mysection.sty` package:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mysection}

\newcommand\mysection[2]{%
    \section{#1}%
  \label{#2}%
}
\endinput
```

more interesting is file `mysection.4ht`, where the command is redefined to declare next file name:

```
\RequirePackage{xstring}
\let\my:section\mysection

\def\strip:sec#1:#2@{#1-#2}
\renewcommand\mysection[2]{%
  \edef\my:label{\detokenize{#2}}
  \edef\my:colon{\detokenize{:}}
  \StrSubstitute\my:label{\my:colon}{-}[\temp]
  \NextFile{\temp.html}
\my:section{#1}{#2}%
}
```

because `\label` contains `:` character, which is illegal in file names on the web, we need to replace it with something safe, such as `-`. We need to play with `\detokenize` commands because `:` has changed catcode in the `.4ht` files.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\NextFile` to force the name of the next file:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First}\label{sec:first}
A first section \autoref{sec:first}.

\NextFile{secinserted}
\section{Inserted}\label{sec:inserted}
An inserted section \autoref{sec:inserted}


\section{Second}\label{sec:second}
A second section \autoref{sec:second}.
\end{document}
```