# htlatex: use the argument of \label as the value of the attribute id in the HTML file

Tags: tex4ht, conversion, htlatex

I have been using htlatex to convert my LaTeX files to HTML. In my experience, htlatex doesn't use the argument of `\label` associated to a section in the LaTeX file to assign the value of `id`in the HTML file. Here is an example. Suppose one of my sections in the LaTeX file has the label `\label{sec:1}`. I would like the `id` attribute in the HTML file to be `id=sec:1`. How can I accomplish that? I have been trying to use a configuration file as described [here](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht/wiki/tex4ht-tutorial#configurations), but I haven't been successful.

Comment: this is possible to achive only using post-processing the HTML file. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260957/2891

Comment: @michal.h21 That's helpful! I didn't know that `make4ht` could be used to postprocess the HTML file.

Comment: it is in fact one of the main `make4ht` features, as `tex4ht` output often needs some post-processing :)